# How to bold the selected text in QTextEditor in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a problem and this problem is that I can't make the current selected text bold. I select part of the text and when I try to bold the current selected text. I got all text bolded insted of that part. so where is the problem ?

In short. I want to make bold the word 'loves'

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import sip



class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 700, 700)
        self.te = QTextEdit(self)
        self.te.setText('sad man loves sad women')

        self.button = QPushButton("bold the text", self)
        self.button.move(150, 200)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.bold_text)

        self.document = self.te.document()
        self.cursor = QTextCursor(self.document)

    def bold_text(self):
        # bold the text
        
        self.cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Start)
        self.cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfLine, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        self.format = QTextCharFormat()
        self.format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        self.cursor.mergeCharFormat(self.format)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're moving the cursor to the `Start` of the document and then to the `EndOfLine`. So you're setting the bold format on the full first line, completely ignoring the selection.

There's absolutely no need to use QTextDocument or QTextCursor if you want to make bold the current selection, as QTextEdit already provides [`setFontWeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setFontWeight):

```
    def bold_text(self):
        self.te.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
```

Note that you should not use a persistent reference to the text cursor, nor the document: while it works in your simple case, both the cursor or the document could change, so you should always access them dynamically. Also, you can directly access the text cursor using `textCursor()` of the QTextEdit.

<sup>Unrelated, but still important: avoid fixed geometries, and always prefer [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead.</sup>

Comment: is there any way to save changes that happend to the text in 'QTextEdit'. for example I bolded word 'loves' and I want to close the app and open it again nut I found that the word 'loves' isn't bold... can I use sql file to store the word postion and bold it again when I open the app ?

Comment: @ZaIon use `toHtml()` to get the "source" and save it in any way you need, then restore it using `setHtml()`. See the [`html` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop) of QTextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
palette = QtGui.QPalette()
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtCore.Qt.blue)
font = QtGui.QFont("MS UI Gothic", 9, QtGui.QFont.Bold)

self.te.setText('10')
self.te.setPalette(palette)
self.te.setFont(font)
```